# Automatically login to moodle when login to another site

Tags: php, cookies, curl, moodle

I was wondering is it possible to automatically login to moodle after loging-in in aonther site? I tried to use curl but it seems not really working.

This is my testing code:

```
//set POST variables
$url = "http://moodlesite.com/login/index.php";

$fields = array(
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password'
);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I notice that after moodle login to the system, they redirect it again to http://moodlesite.com/login/index.php?testsession=userid and they need cookies it this case.

Comment: If it is a well built website, they shouldn't allow you to send a POST of username and password through CURL without the information being submitted from their own native form.  They should be preventing against CSRF.  I don't know much about moodle though.

Comment: What was the end result?

Answer (score 8):

you can create a customized page for login into moodle.

code for that page .

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$dashboard = $CFG->wwwroot;
$user = authenticate_user_login($name, $password);
if(complete_user_login($user))
{
echo "login";
}
else
{
   echo "not login";
}



?>
```

After creating that page you can pass name and password for login .

Answer (score 1):

Not like that, Moodle needs to setup a session in your browser in order for you to be logged in. In general your requirement sounds strange - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

If you'd prefer to avoid your users logging in twice, you would be better implementing some sort of single sign on system:

- Moodle supports CAS as standard ( http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/CAS_server_(SSO) )
- Other add-on authentication plugins such as SAML and OAuth [are available.](https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=21)

If none of those suit, you can also create your own authentication plugin. See [Authentication plugins](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins) in Moodle docs and [lib/authlib.php](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/authlib.php#L86) for details.